# decipher a file format called .EWB

Tags: compression, winrar

I have a file which I know that contains a bunch of compressed files inside with some kind of a header. 
Can anyone tell me how to unpack it?

file format is .EWB, which stands for EasyWorshipBible.
I know its possible as I've seen it being done. But they didn't tell me how.

I tried using hex editors and winRAR. But non of them seem to get the files correct.

Answer (score 0):

In an example I found, each entry begins with hex 51 4b 03 04, followed by six more bytes of information, followed by a zlib stream.  When the zlib streams are decompressed, they have the format "1:1 text line ...", blank line, "1:2 text line ...", etc.  However the text does not seem to match the extraction I found along with the example, so I suspect that the text is encoded or encrypted somehow.

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: can u show me that example?
how did u decompress it?

Yes they come as 1:1 text /n 1:2 text and so on. But thats supposed to be a text file? along with another text file called DATA.
 Is that possible?

Comment: Do you have a `.ewb` file?  If so, search for the hex string, and then use [zlib](http://zlib.net) to decompress starting after that string and after the six bytes that follow.  Repeat.

Comment: but I have no idea how to use it :D :D

Comment: You'll need to learn.  This is a programming forum.  Read zlib.h and look at the examples, including http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html .